# Fooling CSS Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries, tablet

I use a tablet for all my schoolwork because I don't have a good computer, but websites often come up in mobile device format. Is there a way to set my browser to tell websites that it is a computer, and not a tablet? If it were possible, would this cause any other problems, like disabling the touchscreen, or anything like that?

Comment: Use a proxy maybe, or something that renders the page server-side and only shows a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple different ways to tell if you're using a tablet. Typically it's either by:

- screen size (noting the typical width/height ratios of devices) and then styling by media query
- the window.navigator object in the browser is aware of a handful of useful info, such as OS and browser details

Each site will determine this differently so I wouldn't be confident there's a catch-all solution to this one...that being said sometimes landscape will get desktop styling if the devs used the sizing method   ¯_(ツ)_/¯